# Appending an Array at a specific Index in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this.

```
    [['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 0], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
```

and I would like to change one of the zeros to 1. How would I direct a .append to the 0 after Joe for example. I am new to python and can not currently use numPy unfortunately. Also how do you get rid of that stupid \n at the end of a few of the lists?

Comment: `change` and `append` have different meaning. You want to change the value or append the new value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list` indexes:

```
>>> mylist = [['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 0], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
>>> mylist[1][1] = 'new_value'
>>> mylist
[['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 'new_value'], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
```

> In `mylist`, in 2nd element (1), in 2nd element of sublist, I set `'new_value'`

And for `\n`, you can use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
>>> mylist = [['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 0], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
>>> mylist = [[i.strip(), j] for i, j in mylist]
>>> mylist
[['Bob', 0], ['Joe', 0], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
```

> Use a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and apply `strip` to 1st element of
>   all sublists.

Comment: Change the zero to one, not append a new zero. OP is not very clear tho.

Answer (score 1):

it wont let me comment, but I wanted to add to zulu's answers:

```
>>>mylist = [['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 0], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
#so far so good, but change mylist[1][0] to mylist[1][1]
>>>mylist[1][1] = 1
>>>mylist
[['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 1], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]
```

you can access an element of a list using [int]
so, mylist[1] is the element of mylist. mylist[1] also happens to be a list. lets say this (assume I didnt change the value yet):

```
>>>inside_list = mylist[1]
>>>inside_list
['Joe\n', 0]
```

now I can access this inside list. 0 is the number i want to replace, at index 1, so we can do this:

```
>>>inside_list[1] = 1
>>>inside_list
['Joe\n', 1]
```

as a side note, since 0 is an integer, you can also do this:

```
>>>inside_list[1]+=1
>>>inside_list
['Joe\n', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`>>>input = [['Bob\n', 0], ['Joe\n', 0], ['Bill', 0], ['Steve', 0], ['Judy', 0]]`
`>>>output = map(lambda x: [x[0].rstrip(), x[1] or 1], input)`

`>>>output`

`>>>[['Bob', 1], ['Joe', 1], ['Bill', 1], ['Steve', 1], ['Judy', 1]]`